# How to remove df rows if the timestamp is inside at least one of given time intervals?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm given two (pandas) data frames:

- `data`: with time-stamps columns `ts` and other data columns `val1`, and `val2`.
- `intervals`: with two columns, `start` and `end`, that describe a series of time intervals in which `data` is corrupted

my goal - replace all row values in `data` with `NaN` if that row's `ts` is within some range described by `start`, `end`. (Namely, replace the `i`'th row in `data` with [`NaN`,...,`NaN`] if there exists some row `j` in `intervals` such that the `ts_i` is in [`start_j,end_j`])

My current (naive) solution, iterates the ranges using a `for` loop:

```
def _remove_corruptions(corruption_filename: str, df_to_clean: pd.DataFrame):
    corruption_timestamps = pd.read_csv(corruption_filename)
    for j, row in tqdm(corruption_timestamps.iterrows()):
        start, end = row['start'], row['end']
        df_to_clean[(start <= df_to_clean['ts']) & (df_to_clean['ts'] <= end)] = np.nan
    return df_to_clean
```

Can I vectorize this process somehow?

---

an example is provided below:

```
intervals = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2019-06-23', '2020-01-10'], 'end': ['2019-06-24', '2020-01-12']})

        start         end
0  2019-06-23  2019-06-24
1  2020-01-10  2020-01-12

data = pd.DataFrame({'ts': ['2019-06-23', '2019-10-24', '2020-01-11'], 'val1': [1, 1, 1], 'val2': [2, 2, 2]})

           ts  val1  val2
0  2019-06-23     1     2
1  2019-10-24     1     2
2  2020-01-11     1     2
```

required out:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'ts': [np.nan, '2019-10-24', np.nan], 'val1': [np.nan, 1, np.nan], 'val2': [np.nan, 2, np.nan]})

           ts  val1  val2
0         NaN   NaN   NaN
1  2019-10-24   1.0   2.0
2         NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

intervals = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2019-06-23', '2020-01-10'], 'end': ['2019-06-24', '2020-01-12']})
data = pd.DataFrame({'ts': ['2019-06-23', '2019-10-24', '2020-01-11'], 'val1': [1, 1, 1], 'val2': [2, 2, 2]})


def find_corrupted(x):
    # returns a list of all data index numbers where data.ts are between start and end
    return data[((data.ts >= x['start']) & (data.ts <= x['end']))].index.values

# applying a list of index numbers to a new column in intervals
intervals['corrupt'] = intervals.apply(lambda x: find_corrupted(x), axis=1)

# creating list of unique index numbers
mask = intervals.corrupt.explode().unique()


data.loc[data.iloc[mask].index, :] = np.nan
```

**OUTPUT**

```
          ts  val1  val2
0         NaN   NaN   NaN
1  2019-10-24   1.0   2.0
2         NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
interval_dict = dict(zip(intervals['start'],intervals['end'])) # {'2019-06-23': '2019-06-24', '2020-01-10': '2020-01-12'}
data['check'] = data['ts'].apply(lambda x: any(x >= k and x <= v for k,v in interval_dict.items())) # check ts value. If ts value in range return True
data.loc[data['check'].eq(True), data.columns] = np.nan # if check is True replace rows with nan

data = data.drop('check',axis=1)
```

Or one line:

```
data.loc[data['ts'].apply(lambda x: any(x >= k and x <= v for k,v in dict(zip(intervals['start'],intervals['end'])).items())).eq(True), data.columns] = np.nan
```

**Output**:

```
          ts  val1  val2
0        NaT   NaN   NaN
1 2019-10-24   1.0   2.0 
2        NaT   NaN   NaN
```

**Note**: Make sure the date columns are of type datetime before you start.

```
intervals['start']=pd.to_datetime(intervals['start'])
intervals['end']=pd.to_datetime(intervals['end'])
data['ts']=pd.to_datetime(data['ts'])
```